# How to detect changes in text in many JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtabbedpane

I would like to create simply text editor with dynamic amount of tabs. Every tab consist of text field, where someone can load text file and edit or write own text.

I would like to detect changes in tabs, I mean when someone change file and wants close then I'd like to show a dialog about whether you want save changes or no. this is reason why I'd like to follow changes which user committed.

So I have

`JTabbedPane tabbedPane` with `JtextPane textPane`

```
private LinkedList<Boolean> changedList = new LinkedList<Boolean>(); // here I thought of collecting information about changes but it was silly idea.
```

This is function which I create new Tab

```
 public void newTab()
    {
        tabbedPane.addTab("tab-" + counter++, new JTextPane());
        int totalTabs = tabbedPane.getTabCount();
      
        selected = tabbedPane.getComponentAt(totalTabs-1);
        changedList.add( totalTabs-1, false);
        textPane = (JTextPane)selected;

        textPane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    }
```

these are function from interface

```
   @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
       changedList.add(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex(), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        changedList.add(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex(), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        changedList.add(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex(), true);
    }
```

This is how I've tried to save

```
 public void saveAfterChange()
        {
            if (changedList.get(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex()))
            {
                int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Save?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)
                {
                    save();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you open the program and fill your textfields you already have something saved somewhere in a `.txt` file or somewhere, store the oldValues in a variable and compare them against what's written in the textfields, if they're different show your dialog. If you need further help consider posting a proper [mre] that we can copy-paste and reproduce your issue

Comment: *JTabbedPane tabbedPane with JtextPane textPane* - when I did something like this I actually create a class that contained all the information about my "editor". So you could have a JPanel with the JTextPane/JScrollPane added to the panel. Then you track information about the file you are editing. For example you would keep the "file name". Then instead of keeping your "changedList" you would just keep a boolean variable in the class that is updated by your DocumentListener. You then create methods to access the filename and the changed boolean variable.